# How Can I perform a check to see if a record has a foreign Key?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Is there some way to perform a check whether to see or not if a table record has a foreign key before I delete it or update it?.

I have this code using a delete:

But I get this error:

"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`prueba`.`permiso`, CONSTRAINT `permiso_id_ap_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_ap`) REFERENCES `at` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `at` where `id` = 5)"

Controller:

```
    public function deleteSede(Request $id) {
    $sedes=at::find($id->id)->delete();        

    /* if $sedes thrown a foreign key error do this...else do this other
       thing      
    */

     return redirect("/");

    }
```

Tables used:

```
Schema::create('sede', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id')->autoIncrement();
            $table->string("nit",9);
            $table->string("rs",40)
                ; //razon Social
        });

  Schema::create('permiso', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('id')->autoIncrement();
            $table->integer("id_vinp")->unsigned();
            $table->integer("id_ap")->default(0)->unsigned();
            $table->tinyInteger("orden")->default(0);
            $table->tinyInteger("aFinal")->default(0);
            $table->tinyInteger("pFinal")->default("0");
            $table->foreign("id_vinp")->references("id")->on("v_p");
            $table->foreign("id_ap")->references("id")->on("at");

        });

  Schema::create('v_fpat', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('id')->autoIncrement();
            $table->integer("id_vp")->unsigned();
            $table->integer("id_at")->unsigned();
            $table->integer("id_fp")->unsigned();
            $table->foreign("id_vp")->references("id")->on("v_p");
            $table->foreign("id_at")->references("id")->on("at");
            $table->foreign("id_fp")->references("id")->on("forpago");
        });
```

html:

```
<form action="{{route("sede.destroy",["id"=>$sede->id])}}" method="POST">

 @method("DELETE")

  <input type="submit" value="Delete Sede">

  @csrf

</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::delete("deleteSede","ControllerTodo@deleteSede")->name("sede.destroy");
```

Comment: You've already have that information `$table->foreign(...)`.

Comment: add this in you're foreign key constraint `->onDelete('cascade')`

Comment: You can just wrap your code in a `try-catch` and check the exception to determine if it failed because of the foreign key constraint failing.

Comment: apokryfo, your solution is what I was looking for, thanks !!